# Calculating Volatility Parameter using Closing Prices

Tags: volatility

Say you have 3 closing prices...

101
100
102

How would one calculate the standard volatility parameter using these values? I am quite confused, it seems simple enough though.

Answer (score 1):

With 3 closing prices you have 2 returns. You can compute standard deviation of those two returns as a proxy of historical volatility. However, with that number of observations there is nothing you can conclude as for sure the you will not be able to reject the null of 0 volatility.

Comment: yes, I get that. But whats the formulation I would use here?
I know its not very accurate.

Comment: Simply, compute returns as $R_{t}=P_{t+1}/P_t - 1$ and then standard deviation: $\sigma = \sqrt{( \frac{1}{T-1}\sum_{t=1}^T (R_t - \mu)^2)}$ where $\mu$ is the sample mean of returns.